# Maven version not displaying in Macbook Air

Tags: maven

> Blockquote

i have installed "apache-maven-3.6.3" on mac with OS-Catalina. I have kept "apache-maven-3.6.3" folder under "/Users/ak/Applications" interesting part is I don't see any .m2 folder under "/Users/ak" even after pressing CMD+SHIFT+. I can see all hidden folders except '.m2' so I went ahead and created manually not sure if this is the reason for not seeing "mvn version"

afterward created one txt file '-.bash_profile' under "/User/ak" and provided following path, saved and closed it

```
export M2_HOME=/Users/ak/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.3
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

and from terminal I have provided "ak@As-MacBook-Air ~ % source .bash_profile"

```
and when I run "ak@As-MacBook-Air ~ % mvn -version" it displays the version but the moment I close the terminal and reopens it with command "mvn -version" it won't display any version in order to see version I need to run source .bash_profile every time whenever I open the terminal
```

Please help to fix

Comment: First of all, please format this question into something readable.

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow so not sure how to edit

Comment: Then read the help section.

Comment: i have edited the content

Comment: Take my advice: Try to edit the content _properly_ and you double the chance that someone helps you. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting